# call childrens method from parent

Tags: c#, list, oop, inheritance, types

I have a `List<GameObject>` called `MyGameObjects`.
I have a class called `DrawableGameObject` that inherits from `GameObject`. Inside my list there are not only `GameObject`s but also `DrawableGameObject`s.

`DrawableGameObject` has a property called `Animation` which `GameObject` has not.
I want to do following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGameObjects.Count; ++i) {
    if (MyGameObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(DrawableGameObject)) {
        // use Animation property of MyGameObjects[i] here...
    }
}
```

But it won't let me.
If there is a way to do this please help me ^^

Comment: Why not restructure your code so that all objects *can* have animation, but only some of them do, then you can write your code using the base class as though animation will be available, except that it will not animate anything. You should look into Liskovs substitution principle, part of the SOLID principles.

Comment: Think virtual methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the object and access its members.  Something like this:

```
foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects)
    if (gameObject is DrawableGameObject)
        (gameObject as DrawableGameObject).Animation();
```

Or, closer to how you're doing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Count; i++)
    if (gameObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(DrawableGameObject))
        ((DrawableGameObject)gameObjects[i]).Animation();
```

You can also optimize this a little bit by determining the cast only once and then performing a much faster null check:

```
foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects)
{
    var obj = gameObject as DrawableGameObject;
    if (obj != null)
        obj.Animation();
}
```

Note however that is is a pretty glaring violation of [Liskov Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Your code is clearly operating on the wrong abstractions.  There isn't enough information in the question to make concrete suggestions on the matter, but your types aren't designed correctly if you need to cast them in this manner.

Comment: if (gameObject is DrawableGameObject)
        (gameObject as DrawableGameObject).Animation();
is not as efficient as:
var obj = gameObject as DrawableGameObject);
if (obj != null)
        obj.Animation();

Comment: @rbaghbanli: True, but I highly doubt micro-optimizations are really an issue here.  Still, it's worth noting.

Comment: i have thought about adding the `Animation` property to the `GameObject` class as well in order to be able to use it after checking the type but that would have ended in `DrawableGameObject` being completely empty and `GameObject` being a huge mess.

Comment: @NylonFreak: Well, to be fair, the code is already a bit of a mess given what you're trying to accomplish here.  I'd recommend taking your object/inheritance model over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for some advice on a cleaner object-oriented approach.

Comment: @David look at the comment on rbaghbanlis answer. what do you think?

Comment: @NylonFreak: You're suggesting putting a method on objects which may not actually need it and then defining a property to indicate whether or not that method actually does anything?  No.  That's... much worse.  The overall goal is to have a set of interfaces, abstract types, and concrete types which encapsulate and define exactly the functionality they represent.  If you have a collection of things which need to be "animated" then everything in that collection should be "animatable".

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to cast it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGameObjects.Count; ++i) {
    if (MyGameObjects[i].GetType() == typeof(DrawableGameObject)) {
        ((DrawableGameObject)MyGameObjects[i]).Animation;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much... i was planning to add the `Animation` property to `GameObject` and only use it when i checked the type. That would have ended in a huge mess... I had tried to cast the object but i did it like `(DrawableGameObject)myGameObjects[i].Animation`.

Comment: It's a subtle difference that tripped me up too, years ago. When you think about it `(DrawableGameObject)myGameObjects[i].Animation` is actually trying to cast the return value of `Animation` to `DrawableGameObject`

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast it to a `DrawableGameObject`:

```
for( int i = 0; i < MyGameObjects.Count; i++ )
    if( MyGameObjects[i] is DrawableGameObject )
    {
        var drawable = (DrawableGameObject)MyGameObjects[i];
        ...
    }
```

Or, to be a little bit more efficient:

```
for( int i = 0; i < MyGameObjects.Count; i++ )
{
    var drawable = MyGameObjects[i] as DrawableGameObject;
    if( drawable != null )
        ...
}
```

The `as` operator will return null if the cast is invalid.